# How to match a nut to this threaded stud (gaps in thread)

Tags: fastener, thread

**Context**
The attached photo is a stud in the roof of my vehicle, to which I wish to attach a roof rack. The roof rack should come with nuts to attach it, but they are missing. I need to find an alternative before the manufacturer can send replacements. [Update] The vehicle is a 2017 Chrysler Pacifica. The studs were used to hold plastic clips in place, which held a trim piece (covering the gutter) in place.

[image: threaded stud]

**Questiona**
What is the name of this type of thread? (with gaps)
How do I match a nut to it?
Why does it have those gaps?

**What I already tried**
I tried an M6-1.0 nut (close match based on the OD of the stud). I can do a couple of turns with fingers, then it gets too tight. It's easy to put on with a wrench (i.e. very little torque), but when removed the threads show some change of shape. Normally I'd consider any change to the threads to be a sign that the nut is not right, and stop right there. But in this case the threads are strange to start with - it's a design I've never seen before. It occurred to me that the thread may be designed to deform slightly as a sort of built-in loc-tite (with the constraint that they can't be used multiple times). I.e. using the ductility of the threads to prevent the nut shaking lose. Or maybe that's just wishful thinking :)

Comment: I’m curious about the thread spacing. When you hold a 6.0x1mm bolt next to the displayed fastener, does the thread pitch line up perfectly?

Comment: Get a thread pitch gauge and find out exact specification, then you'll know what nut to use.
I don't know the name of a thread with gaps like that, not something I've seen too often.
I like your thinking about the thread being able to deform due to the gaps but I wouldn't think thats the case, if they wanted nuts to stay in place against vibration etc. then the manufacturer of the roof rack kit could use stop nuts with nylon inserts.

Comment: @tom Now that I have a closer look, I wonder if its screw type thread at all. Those lines look horizontal. If they are, then my guess is that the body trim which you removed to uncover those, is pushed into place over that.
I assume you didn't have to unscrew any nuts to remove the trim from that roof channel, if you did then obviously you could of just re-used those nuts to secure the roof rack.
So, how did you remove the roof channel trim? Did you just pry it off?

Comment: Add more info about the specific car.  Someone on here meh have the identical car and be able to help.

Comment: Where I have seen these they are often just for holding trim in place.  The nut has been made of plastic and the threads cut themselves.

Comment: I think that the paint on the bolt makes it hard to put on the nut. Perhaps clean it gently with a wire brush

Comment: Please identify the manufacturer and model of the vehicle.

Comment: Lots of good comments - thanks. I updated the question. I'm going to add my own answer.

Comment: @tom How did you remove the roof trim? Did you simply pry it off or did you have to remove nuts or screws?
Because, if you pried it off, then I would say that thread is not a screw thread at all. The roof trim is probably held by plastic parts which that stud is pushed into when the trim was put in place, the plastic tabs deform around those grooves and grab on. So, would be easy to push on when installing but harder to remove.
How did you get the roof trim off and can you post a picture of the roof trim underside so we can see how it attaches?

Comment: @tom What Chrysler do you have, a 300c?

Comment: @tom As I said earlier, I think the roof trim was held in place by a design where the plastic is pushed over that bolt and grabs onto those threads, I don't think its meant for screwing nuts on. Pic shows the similar method I'm suggesting.
https://www.stanleyengineeredfastening.com/-/media/web/sef/assets/product-assets/dodge_taper_tuff_duo_thumbnail/tiv_375x300.jpg?h=300&w=375&hash=7528D8CDFA17C4B3D5739A3DDD6712E0

Comment: @tom Found further evidence that those stud types are supposed to be used with push-nuts. The roof gutter trim must have been pressed down and it held in place with a plastic push-nut type mechanism underneath the trim piece.
The thread type is simply called 'xmas-tree' thread. Push-nuts can be used with threaded or unthreaded studs. Follow links for pics.

https://www.stanleyengineeredfastening.com/-/media/web/sef/assets/product-assets/tucker/thread-type_paintclearing.jpg?h=300&w=560&la=en&hash=F13838127CEFEE9CE44A04BC475F5225

https://www.seastrom-mfg.com/sheet_metalnuts.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I can now partially answer this question.

**How do I match a nut to it?**
There is no nut that fits this stud with finger strength only. This is likely due to both the shape and the fact it is painted. I managed to get hold of the Chrysler official nut that threads onto this stud. It is an M6-1.0 thread (as confirmed by threading with finger strength only onto a regular M6-1.0 bolt). However a regular M6-1.0 nut cannot thread onto the stud with finger strength only, so it cannot be said that this stud is regular M6-1.0

**What is the name of this type of thread? (with gaps)**
Unknown. Three theories:

1. It's partially depitched for retention: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distorted_thread_locknut
2. It's just hard to thread because it's painted
3. The slots in the thread are designed to allow plastic retention clips (for trim) to be better secured (or removed?)

**Why does it have those gaps?**
See above

I think the only way to get a better answer is to find the engineer who designed / specified it.

Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: The Chrysler parts book will have a diagram, showing this part and the others that surround and connect to it. Whatever fits onto the stud will be another part, and have a part number.

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of self-tapping screw; the gaps are there to allow cut material to displace and to provide increased friction against the fastening coming undone.  I’d guess it’s intended to screw into plastic (nylon or ABS) or a soft metal.  You could improve a bit using a drilled piece of plastic: possibly you could screw down several layers of thinner material if you don’t have a suitable block to hand.